# Response Faster / respond faster?

Tags: grammar, verbs, verb-agreement

I am looking for a new laptop, and as I scrolled down the page of this specific model, I encountered this:

[image]

So, bottom line: shouldn’t it be *Respond Faster*?

I am didn’t post a link because I’m not sure if it’s allowed to link to other websites, and since I don’t want to promote anything.

So just out of curiosity, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it should be *respond faster*. But I'd say this concern falls squarely under the advice of *don't sweat the small stuff*.

Comment: That's true, it was just bugging me... and I wasn't sure if my grammar was a little rusty..

Comment: @DanBron I don't agree, I think this is short for [the] response [is] faster, just as the line above means [you can] hear any sound in [the] game.

Comment: @Mynamite That interpretation makes less sense in context (and if they meant that, the idiomatic way to phrase it would've been *faster response*, anyway), and the very fact they elided the definite article in "*[the] game*" lends credence to the theory that these people are not native speakers, and are given to solecisms.

Comment: @DanBron I agree they do not sound like native speakers, which is why they wouldn't necessarily use 'faster response'. But it's just another interpretation - as you said, best not sweat the small stuff :)

Comment: @Mynamite Yes, they should have said "respond faster", but being non-native speakers they likely don't have a grasp on the subtleties of English. But the bottom line is we all know what they meant to say, so it matters not.

Comment: So nobody should mention the mismatched sentence and fragments, or the surfeit of exclamation marks. Or the quality of the graphics.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).